# Is a form necessary on .ajaxSubmit() if calling it from the file input button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, ajaxform

I'm following examples from the [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) to asynchronously upload a image to my server. I have only one button, 'Add Photos' that gets pressed to select a photo. Then the post to my server occurs to save the image and refreshes the images below in a thumbnail gallery. Do I even need a form here? It seems like I don't because I'm not using a submit button, I'm submitting after I add the photo. Will this trip me up when I have to display all images and refresh the page with new images? Just curious for feedback.
Here is my html form.

```html
<form id="imageform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" />
  <input type="button" value="Add Photos" class="btn" id="pictureupload" />
</form>
<h1>Output Div (#output2):</h1>
<div id="output">AJAX response will replace this content.</div>
```

Here is my javascript.

```js
$("#pictureupload").click(function () {
  document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();
});

$('#selectedFile').change(function() {
    var uploadImageUrl = $('#imageform').data('url');
    var options = {
        target: '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success: showResponse,  // post-submit callback 

        // other available options: 
        url:       '/ManageSpaces/UploadImage', //uploadImageUrl, //'/ManageSpaces/UploadImage',         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        type:      'post'        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    };

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    //$('#imageform').submit(function () {
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        //return false;
    //});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the form because you are using it to send your file, but you can get rid of it if you use the filesystem api and send the file yourself.

This [hmtl5 rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) on the filesystem api is helpful if you want to upload files without using forms.

Comment: do you know if there are any examples using this in ASP MVC and passing the data to a controller?